# MySQL Query <table_name> based on column value return

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, entity-attribute-value

This may be a ridiculous question with a far more straightforward solution than I am leaning towards here, but I'm hoping someone can give me a good solution!

Let's say I have a database with multiple tables that look something like this:

```
**table_users**:
id, username, email, password

*example*

testuser, testuser@test.com, 123456

**table_services**:
id, service_name

*example*

0, Shipping
1, Payments
2, Packaging

**table_markets:**
id, market_name

*example*

0, Fashion
1, Food
2, Healthcare

**table_user_attributes:**
user_id, table_name, attr_id

*example*

0, 'table_markets', 1
0, 'table_services', 0
0, 'table_services', 2
```

In this example, the user attributes table would have user id of 0 associated with 'Food' market and the 'Shipping' and 'Packaging' services.

The reason I have the table name in this attributes column in this example, is these attribute ID's can come from different tables (services, markets in this case) and I need to kow which table to look up the attr_id for.

My **FIRST** question is - im guessing im doing the table name setup in a very dumb way, is there a better way to locate what table something might be coming from, and then be able to use that in your next query?

my second question is, assuming this is correct, how would I then set up a query to do something like:

look up user, get user id, look up all entries from table_user_attributes with the user id I have received, and then (here's the question part) take the table name and query those with the ids... i.e.:

```
SELECT table_users.username, table_users.id, table_user_attributes.table_name, 
table_user_attributes.attr_id 
FROM table_user_attributes 
INNER JOIN table_users ON table_user_attributes.user_id=table_users.id
```

If I'm understanding right, that query would get me the users info, as well as the table_user_attributes associated with that user id, but then I have no idea how I then pull the appropriate services/markets from this info.

I hope that makes sense, it's a strange question - basically im aiming to keep user attributes all in one table, but the ID's that they point to can come from multiple different tables, and I need a way to know from which table each ID associated with the USER id comes from so i can look it up and get its name.

The problems likely enter in:

Database design - I'm quite sure this is not perfect (also this doesn't exist, this is me writing up a theoretical example, I haven't built any tables yet, set primary keys, etc. trying to wrap my head around this issue first.

Query - which will change depending on the design - but if, on the off chance I used what I have above, I don't know how id make that query work.

Probably going about it wrong - so any help is much appreciated!

*EDIT*

I also realize the easiest (and possibly best) solution is to have a separate table for each thing, like:

table_user_services
table_user_markets

etc - but I guess I just want to check if that is the most efficient solution or if this is a more btree/sql friendly solution.

Comment: TL;DR; See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: as mentioned, this is not a datbase that actually exists, and this example is just meant to illustrate what Im getting it - i know my setup wont actualyl work - what im asking for is help in determining what the best set up would be for actually making these tables and keeping things efficient. Im not sure i can create example tables illustrating what im after as I dont know if its even possible - i mentioned in my edit i know how to make it work in a more standard way - but im curious if there is a more efficient solution others know about. Thanks for the info though - I will use it next time